# Sign Windows Electron app without purchasing certificate

Tags: reactjs, windows, electron, certificate, electron-builder

I have one Electron project and want to build windows and mac app.
I build Mac app with developer ID but in Windows I think I must purchase certificate. But It's too expensive. Please help me on get free certificate of Windows.

Comment: There are no free certificates. You can "self sign" but that is not for production.

Comment: How can I self sign? And can other guys see the app with warning?

Comment: One way is you can unpack the app.asar and inject the license keys or any response data you got from your mac app.

Comment: @DevLover did you find any solution to this?